# Cursor method dosen't work between the stages in JavaFX

Tags: webview, javafx, cursor

i'm trying to make a browser that loads a web page in `WebView` and before i have a button in `Stage1` this button should set the cursor `WAIT` while loading the web page in `Stage2` i tried this code :

```
   @FXML
private void tabfirst (ActionEvent ee) throws IOException { // for tha Chooser frame text.

            String hh = text11.getText(); //from Stage1
            Socket socket = new Socket();
    try {

        //open cursor
        panoo.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT); //this component is in Stage1
        que.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT); //this component is in Stage1
        hboxbuttons.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT); //this component is in Stage1
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT); //this component is in Stage2
        //do work
        URL url = new URL (hh);
        url.getContent();
        WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine();
        myWebEngine.load(url+"");
        //close the window chooser
        Stage stage = new Stage();
          Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml"));
          Scene scene = new Scene(root);
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });
        //close cursor
         panoo.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        que.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        hboxbuttons.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
    }
   catch (IOException e){
       final  Stage stg = new Stage();           
        stg.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        stg.initOwner(stg);
        stg.setTitle("Cannot connect to the internet /n Please Verify your connection internet");
        labelno.setText("Cannot connect to the internet...");
        //close chooser
        Stage stage = new Stage();
         Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Choose.fxml"));
         stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {
              @Override public void handle(WindowEvent t) { } });

       //set cursor
         ancpa.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);

   } finally{
       try{ socket.close(); } catch (Exception e){ }
       }

}
```

so please what's wrong with my code can anybody help me thanls in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to cange a the cursor type by clicking on a button in JavaFX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28179935/how-to-cange-a-the-cursor-type-by-clicking-on-a-button-in-javafx)